# How did French people greet in 1400?

Tags: histoire, salutations, ancien-français

How did French people greet in 1400?

In particular I'm looking for french expressions that a peasant like Saint Joan of Arc could have used to greet a friend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use one of the following expressions :

> [Hé,] Que y'a ?

What's up?

> Ayez un bon jour

Literally "Have a good day", used to say "Hello" (became "bonjour").

> Diex vos sait (very formal)/Diex beneï toi

"God bless you", very ancient, used to start or end a conversation.

You can find more information in « [Quelques formules de salutation en ancien français](https://tidsskrift.dk/index.php/revue_romane/article/view/11277/21396) » (Anker Teilgàrd Laugesen, in *Revue Romane*, Vol. 8, 1973, 1-2).

Comment: Could you please provide a proof (link) for this?

Comment: @BorbagUskada do you know if "Ajez un bon jour" would be a proper greet for a new friend? I mean: today I can greet a just known friend of a friend: "Bonjour, je m'appelle Giacomo". Would "Ajez un bon jour" be equivalent to this use of bonjour?

Comment: Why would you tell a known friend your name? If you know him, shouldn't he already know your name? Seems superfluous…

Comment: No I'm thinking of the case "friend of a friend": I meet a friend of a friend and I present myself.

Comment: @GiacomoTesio Yes, you could use "Ayez un bon jour(bon jor)" as the equivalent, but in this case I think "Diex vos sait" is maybe more adapted
You can find here some details and more informations : https://tidsskrift.dk/index.php/revue_romane/article/view/11277/21396

"Diex vos sait" come from latin, but was very used in old french.
"Que y'a" is very rural and not formal.

Comment: Could you provide a reference about "Que y'a"?

Answer (score 2):

Bonjour!

There is a possibility that many used the traditional *Faire la bise*, which means to give a kiss. This is not just the ordinary peck on the cheek, it is the double cheek kiss that we often see on older foreign films. It is a common way for the French to say their goodbyes and greetings. It is in no way used as a romantic display of affection.

I hope this helped!

**Merci!**